# Is it possible to make Chrome, FF and IE9 treat the display values tableXXX the same?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-9

Please, observe the following simple jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/DaYCa/28/

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container table">
      <div class='thead'>
        <div class='tr'>
          <div class='td'>
            <div class='header'>header</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='tbody'>
        <div class='tr'>
          <div class='td'>
            <div class='content'>content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='tfoot'>
        <div class='tr'>
          <div class='td'>
            <div class='footer'>footer</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: table;
}
.thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
.tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
}
.content {
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background-color: #999;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox and IE9:

[image]

How do I change the code, so that it looks the same as Chrome on all the three browsers?

P.S.
Fixed heights can be used for the header and the footer, but not the content.

Comment: Any reason you're essentially re-creating a table by using divs? Sometimes it's better to use tables.

Comment: @j08691 - think it's pretty clear this isn't the re-creation of a table, but an attempt to make use of the table layout algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your example and re-created it in a table as well to see how the browsers behave. It's exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/scheinercc/hXYVm/

*(tested on Mac OS Firefox Aurora/20 and Chrome latest stable)*

So I guess what Chrome does is a bit of a trick, assuming that this result is what devs usually want.

But how I read the code:

- The `td`s height is defined only by the font size and line height of it's children. A child's 100% height is determined by the parent.
- Adding the height to the `td` will give you a `td` with a 100% height referring to the viewport (in Firefox - and I guess in IE), that means footer and header are not visible if you scroll to the middle of the page.

Chrome assumes again, that this is actually not what we (devs) hoped for and gives the same result as before, by calculating the following.

I'd say, what you want is actually:

```
containerHeight = 100% of page height - (headerContainerHeight + footerContainerHeight)
```

Please find a small JS excample in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/scheinercc/DaYCa/35/

*(tested on Mac OS Firefox Aurora/20 and Chrome latest stable)*

I know it would have been nicer to have a HTML/CSS solution, but I can't think of any atm.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I will wait a bit for someone to give a pure HTML/CSS solution. BTW, your jsFiddle has an error - `window.onload(setContentHeight());window.onresize(setContentHeight());` Does not do what you probably think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code into your .content Css

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Like this in .footer css

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

Then test your firefox browser. It will show similar to chorme.

Comment: Please, modify my jsFiddle to incorporate your changes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DaYCa/30/ try this.. if not work, comment me. I will check again.

Comment: Works neither on FF nor on IE9. Please, install one of them to be able to check yourself before posting an answer.

Comment: Hai... Mr.Mark.. Usually vertical align tag used for table's inline css. But i think you want this function in your div tag. So I search in internet and finally find this way. This way working with Javascript. Kindly see this demo in Chrome and Firefox : http://nerdstogeeks.com/demos/vertical-align-css-demo.html and Reference site : http://blog.nerdstogeeks.com/2011/03/vertical-align-text-in-div-elements.html